# IPython: Keyboard shortcut for navigating top and bottom of codeblock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Lately, I have using IPython and I'm unable to figure out shortcut to move the cursor at the top or the bottom of the code block?

```py
In [58]: def my_decorator(func):
    ...:     @functool.wraps(func)
    ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         print("Calling before the function")
    ...:         func(*args, **kwargs)
    ...:         print("Calling after the function")
    ...:     return wrapper
    ...:
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> should move the cursor to the first column of the first line.
Similarily, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> moves it to the last column of the last line.

Use <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to move between the lines.